# Скрипт бэкапа базы данных

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, скрипт для бэкапа базы (mysql). Нужно, чтобы я мог привязать его к кнопке "экспорт" в админке, и при нажатии на кнопку скрипт экспортировал бы нужные мне таблицы в файл в виде sql кода, а при нажатии на "импорт" исполнял бы этот файл.
Искал готовые решения, но в основном все с веб интерфейсом и кучей настроек, ковырять их довольно-таки долго, а мне нужен простенький скрипт.

Comment: А взять скрипты с phpMyAdmin допустим? Вернее посмотреть принцип их работы!

Comment: [юзеаем поиск же](http://hashcode.ru/questions/99250/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для экспорта:

```
BACKUP TABLE tbl_name[,tbl_name...] TO '/path/to/backup/directory'
```

для импорта:

```
RESTORE TABLE tbl_name[,tbl_name...] FROM '/path/to/backup/directory'
```